# Searching for a fantasy book for a friend very vague details but has a tunnel and a very specific phrase

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a ( possible) YA fantasy book read by my friend in the early 90's (up to about 1995) in the UK.
No idea of age of book and I've ruled out *The Weirdstone of Brisingamen* and *Goblins in the Castle*.

His description is as follows

> "it was from school and contained the line
>
> *“‘hmm’ said the dwarf, ‘thimblewinter’.”"*
>
> This was in the UK. It would have been around 1991-1994 I think. Couldn’t even speculate as to the age of the book. I recall it as being aimed at older children, fantasy genre. They were on a voyage or quest. And they passed through some kind of hole in a mountain."

Comment: Presumably _thimblewinter_ is a pun on _Fimbulwinter_.

Comment: *"Hmm", said the dwarf* - https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hmm+said+the+dwarf%22&sca_esv=573429464&biw=1536&bih=723&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AM9HkKm0D-5_Ky897NwhoAHlNj3uXJd9Ow%3A1697281868634&ei=THcqZb-iJsCfhbIP4fC8wAg&ved=0ahUKEwi_-PPWs_WBAxXAT0EAHWE4D4gQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22hmm+said+the+dwarf%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhQiaG1tIHNhaWQgdGhlIGR3YXJmIkjlHlCsB1i7HXAAeACQAQCYAaEBoAHBBaoBAzMuM7gBA8gBAPgBAYgGAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books

Comment: *"Hm", said the dwarf* - https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hm+said+the+dwarf%22&sca_esv=573429464&biw=1536&bih=666&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AM9HkKl8AiM7jkCyQwsq9L3RlZ3NsdzYIw%3A1697282150761&ei=ZngqZb_wLbCVhbIP6ZmLmAg&ved=0ahUKEwi_u7fdtPWBAxWwSkEAHenMAoMQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22hm+said+the+dwarf%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhMiaG0gc2FpZCB0aGUgZHdhcmYiSOEtUMgrWLcscAB4AJABAJgBW6AB3wOqAQE2uAEDyAEA-AEBiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-books

Comment: Strongly similarities to the Selamillion, a parody of the LOTR books - https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Sellamillion/KNK46e2hKJYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22said+the+dwarf%22+and+%22winter%22&pg=PT86&printsec=frontcover

Comment: In the game *Gods of War: Ragnarok*, "Thimblewinter is used as the name for the Fimbulwinter.

Answer (score 17):

I know you say you've ruled it out, but surely this has to be [The Weirdstone of Brisingamen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Weirdstone_of_Brisingamen) by Alan Garner? The line appears on page 183 of my Collins edition:

> "...Cousin Fenodyree, what make you of those clouds to the north? How is it they have not changed since I saw them under the moon? The wind should have carried them to us long ago."
> "Hm," said the dwarf. "Fimbulwinter?"
> "Ay. They do not mean to lose..."

I believe my school library might also have had a copy in the 90s, and the dates fit as it was published earlier (1960 in the UK). A large part of the book is taken up with the characters travelling through underground tunnels which could match the hole in the mountain your friend remembers.

Comment: Fantastic, it was my first thought, he says nor, but now there's proof! Amazing. Thank you.

Comment: It's been probably 35-40 years since I read this, but the "hole in the mountain" is probably the Wizard's Well on Alderley Edge, which I think is where the two children Susan and Colin first enter Fundindelve with Cadellin. You can visit it, or there are plenty of images on the web.